# Set playback rate on JWPlayer for Android

Tags: android, jwplayer, playback

I'm using JWPlayer for Android to embed a video/audio player on my app. I'd like to offer speed up/slow down buttons but I can't seem to find any way to alter the playback rate of the player. I know it can be done in the web version of JWPlayer, but here there doesn't seem to be such a method.

Could you help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature that JWPlayer is currently working on, but unfortunately is not possible at the moment

Source:
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/questions/17020897-android-sdk-playback-rate?new=17020897